# Is it possible to configure (Thinking) Sphinx on a separate database from the Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

Is it possible to have my app use (in development mode) a SQLite3 adapter, while Sphinx uses Postgres?

I tried to do it by adding the file `config/thinking_sphinx.yml` below, but I get an error message telling me that SQLite3 is not supported. My `config/database.yml` has SQLite3 in development, of course.

```
default: &default
  encoding: utf8
  host: localhost
  adapter: postgresql
  port: 5432
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: ts_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: ts_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: ts_production
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Sphinx, then you need to use either PostgreSQL or MySQL for that environment. So, technically yes, you can use SQLite in development, that will mean you can't use Sphinx or Thinking Sphinx in development, which is I think is a very bad move: I would recommend using the same database in all environments generally (whether or not Sphinx is involved), and especially so in this case, otherwise you won't be able to do anything search-related in your development environment.

Comment: I might not have been clear in my question - what I meant is, in the dev environment, can I have my app's ORM adapter be SQLite, while Sphinx's adapter is Postgres? I was hoping that Sphinx would read `config\thinking_sphinx.yml` if it exists, and maintain a connection to the Postgres server, while simultaneously my app is using the SQLite db... is that possible?

Comment: Why would you be running two different databases for the same environment? Are you expecting the same data in both databases?

Comment: Just to be clear: Sphinx queries against your database to build its index, and then your search queries talk to Sphinx, and Thinking Sphinx translates those results back into ActiveRecord objects (via your database). So, if Sphinx is using PostgreSQL as its database source, that needs to be the same as your app's normal database.

Comment: I noticed the index files after I posted the question ... I thought Sphinx was _using_ the database itself as an index. My bad. Thanks for your quick clarifications!